Trying to blur everything but prefab hdrp
anyone know how to blur background and keep a prefab in focus. I am using hdrp. I looked at options in unity, and see something called volume masks. I found a solution but not sure if there is a better way to mask things not to blur.
in this example he used two cameras.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAopDQDCwak
Why would unity have something called volume mask or maybe using layer masks. I am confused.

id use 2 cameras too

but the stacking like you think doesn't work in hdrp. try it and you will see. unless i am missing something, all the research i have done, seems like it has to be a custom shader pass

I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add SOLVED to the title or edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution that you want to share, do so by writing an answer to the question in the space provided below for that purpose. See Can I answer my own question? for more information.
